# Where is the current version of the Emacs calc?

Tags: emacs, elisp, calc

I lost my installation of Dave Gillespie's calc.el by reinstalling Cygwin.  It is not included with the default Cygwin install of Emacs.  Who is considered the master maintainer these days?  Is version 2.02f still most current?

Answer (score 3):

In the Emacs CVS tree. See [the calc page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/calc.html) and the [Emacs project page](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/emacs/). The root of the calc subtree is [here](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/emacs/lisp/calc/?root=emacs) and you can get the latest version by typing

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.sv.gnu.org:/sources/emacs co emacs/lisp/calc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jouni making it clear that GNU does maintain Emacs Calc, I have figured out that there is a Cygwin install of Emacs that does include Calc.  The necessary step is forcing Cygwin Setup to install Emacs 22.1-3 instead of the default 21.2-13.  I have sent a report to the cygwin@cygwin.com mailing list to get this repaired.